# How to make foreach loop with custom class and List<> in class

Tags: c#

If i have this class:

```
    public class CacheClass
    {
        public string UserID { get; set; }
        public List<string> TabId { get; set; }
        public List<string> State { get; set; }
        public List<string> CanAdmin { get; set; }
    }
```

Then i add value to class and add to cache. I assign to my var type variable cache value:

```
    var k = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Cache[objUserInfo.UserID.ToString()];
```

So, how i can get foreach loop with `var k` and get all value?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you will see `k` is an `object` (hover over `var`), since the [`Cache` dictionary isn't strongly typed](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.cache.item(v=vs.110).aspx). The compiler doesn't know the actual type is `CacheClass`. So step 1 is to cast it. I would prefer to use `as` since it won't throw an exception if casting fails:

```
var k = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Cache[objUserInfo.UserID.ToString()] as CacheClass;
```

Using `as` does require you to to do a `null`-check  to make sure the cast went okay:

```
if (k != null)
{
    foreach (string x in k.State)
    {  }
}
```

Comment: But then i try assign to `var k` with `as CacheClass` I always get null. But without `as CacheClass` i get correct value.

Comment: How and where do you save it then? Are you sure the key still matches?

Comment: Its testing data. Iam saving like that `List<string> temp1 = List<string>(); ... temp1.Add("tabid");...A.TabId=temp1;...System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Cache[objUserInfo.UserID.ToString()] = a; var j = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Cache[objUserInfo.UserID.ToString()] as CacheList;` After button click.

Comment: I think you are assigning that one to the cache, aren't you?

Comment: CacheClass a = new CacheClass(); Yes one.

Comment: You can try fix the cache key to a constant, like "dummy".

Comment: Sorry for late response, but its not fix. I still get null when use `as CacheClass`

Answer (score 2):

You are probably missing the cast

```
var k = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Cache[objUserInfo.UserID.ToString()] as CacheClass;
foreach(var state in k.State) {
    // ...
}
```